# Mondrian webpage layout

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dojo, webui

I'm looking for a sample/code snippet for a Mondrian style page layout for Dojo (Mondrian, not as the software, but the [French Artist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piet_Mondrian)). Users should be able to click on a border to split the available rectangle and have a handle to move the divider and some mechanism (e.g. dragging to the edge) to delete a divider.
I plan to use that for a browser based form layout. So the wireframe would look like a Mondrian painting:
[image: Mondrian painting]

Comment: this link may help. http://www.compositionwithjavascript.com/

Comment: Emir: cool. If you put your answer into an answer instead of a comment I can accept and vote for you

Comment: good to hear the link helped. i added my comment as an answer.

Comment: Looking for something similar but only wanted to point out that even though Mondrian lived in Paris quite a few years he was not French.  He was a Dutch painter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I wrote [BorderContainer](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/layout/BorderContainer.html#dijit-layout-bordercontainer), I used a Mondrian-like image as [one of the tests](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.4.1/dojo-release-1.4.1/dijit/tests/layout/test_BorderContainer.html) to show constraints.   It uses nested BorderContainers (5 region layout)  It's not nearly as pretty as Emir's link.

Comment: But it is Dojo :-) The JS Lib I use every day

Answer (score 3):

You can find a sample javascript code which should help you.

http://www.compositionwithjavascript.com/